Marimo server not starting in VS Code (Error on launching Marimo Notebook)
I had created a Marimo notebook file (.py) from VS Code. Unfortunately, I am now unable to open the file back in Marimo through VS Code because the Marimo server isn't starting. Below is what happens:
Image 1: The server shows as starting, but never fully loads.
Image 1
Expected Behavior: It should work as shown in Image 2, with the Marimo interface in VS Code.
Image 2
Actual Behavior: Instead, I get this as shown in Image 3.
Image 3
What I’ve Tried:

Restarting VS Code.
Creating a new Marimo file.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Not a satisfying answer, but restarting your computer will likely fix it. In the meantime you can run it from the terminal with marimo edit my_notebook.py
You could also try asking this question in the project's discussion forum. The developers are pretty active there.
